# Rails: Why is bundle install frozen up by sassc 2.4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, deployment, capistrano, ubuntu-20.04

I'm trying to deploy my rails app with Capistrano, however, the deploy process (`cap production deploy`) is constantly held up at the line:

`$HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle install --path /home/deploy/appname/shared/bundle --jobs 4 --without development test --deployment -- quiet`

When I ssh into the server and run the same command in the latest release without the `--quiet` flag, I see most gems are installed, but when it gets to

`Installing sassc 2.4.0 with native extensions`

it freezes. If I monitor the CPU with cloud watch (I'm using an EC2 instance running Ubuntu 20.04), I see it also spikes. I've tried removing all dependencies that rely on sassc, but this has proven a really big headache and seems like it shouldn't be necessary. Some dependent gems include my CMS (comfortable mexican sofa), webpacker, and some node dependencies.

I've also tried to install sassc using

`apt-get install sassc`

to no avail (it installs, but bundle install still freezes).

Does anyone have any idea why this gem is having so much trouble installing? Any workarounds/fixes? By the way, the dependencies install and run fine locally on my macOS Catalina machine.

Bonus:
Here's the CPU usage when I run the deploy script:
[image]

credit count:
[image]

credit balance:
[image]

Maybe it's simply not possible to install sassc with the free EC2 plan?

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem in EC2 when bundle, it stop at Installing sassc 2.4.0 with native extensions.

Comment: Facing same issue. Following along the thread https://github.com/sass/sassc-ruby/issues/189

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a problem with sassc version 2.4.0 and rails 6. I changed the version in the Gemfile to 2.1.0 and now it install fast and don't stucks on docker build.

Comment: This seems to be the core of the problem. Using an older version of sassc solves the issue.

Comment: Could you please tell me how was it done ?? forgive me for my ignorance

Comment: @user2609074 add gem `'sassc', '~> 2.1.0'` to your gemfile, run `bundle update sassc` and then install again.

Answer (score 3):

Using an older version of sass solves the issue. I advise changing 6 to 5.1.0 in the Gemfile. This file will be located in your rails folder (the name you used when creating a new rails)

I think Rails 6 is not compatible with Sass 6.0.0's dependencies for some reason.